# Como pegar valor de input checkbox array com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

não estou conseguindo verificar se pelo menos um checkbox foi marcado antes de dar submit no form.

Vi que tem algumas perguntas semelhantes a minha, mas nenhuma das soluções deram certo para mim

Usei o seguinte código e não está dando certo:

```
$("#funcoes_cursos").submit(function(){
            var cursos = $("#funcoes_cursos input[name='cursos[]']").val();
            if(cursos == "" || cursos === undefined){
                alert('Selecione um ou mais cursos para deletar');
                return false;
            }else {
                if( !(confirm("Ao deletar um curso, todos os dados relacionados a ele também serão deletados. Deseja realmente deletar o curso?")) ) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Os inputs estão no formato:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cursos[]" value="">
```

A minha ideia é que antes de mandar o form para página que deleta os cursos selecionados, ele verifique se pelo menos um curso esteja selecionado. Mas do jeito que está ele não pega o valor do input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que `$("#funcoes_cursos input[name='cursos[]']")` devolve uma lista(array) de cursos e não um só, logo o `.val()` apanha apenas o valor do primeiro. Para além disso é necessário ver quais estão `checked`. A contabilização pode ser feita com o `each()`, passando em cada elemento e contando os que estão `checked`:

```
var cursos = $("#funcoes_cursos input[name='cursos[]']"); //apanhar todos

var checkados = 0; //iniciar a contagem
cursos.each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) { //se está marcado conta mais 1
        checkados++; 
    }
});
```

Depois é apenas necessário verificar se a contagem é maior que `0`. Integrando com o seu código ficaria assim:

```js
$("#funcoes_cursos").submit(function() {
  var cursos = $("#funcoes_cursos input[name='cursos[]']");

  var checkados = 0;
  cursos.each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      checkados++;
    }
  });

  if (checkados == 0) {
    alert('Selecione um ou mais cursos para deletar');
    return false;
  } else {
    if (!(confirm("Ao deletar um curso, todos os dados relacionados a ele também serão deletados. Deseja realmente deletar o curso?"))) {
      return false;
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="funcoes_cursos">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cursos[]" value="curso1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cursos[]" value="curso2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cursos[]" value="curso3">

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Uma solução ainda mais simples é utilizar o pseudo seletor `:checked` diretamente na busca dos elementos. Isto vai fazer com que já so obtenha os elementos que estão `checked` e por isso resta apenas saber se obteve algum testando o `length`(quantidade) do que obteve.

Exemplo:

```js
$("#funcoes_cursos").submit(function() {
  //agora buscar somente os checkeds, utilizando :checked no seletor
  var cursos = $("#funcoes_cursos input[name='cursos[]']:checked");
 
  if (cursos.length == 0) {
    alert('Selecione um ou mais cursos para deletar');
    return false;
  } else {
    if (!(confirm("Ao deletar um curso, todos os dados relacionados a ele também serão deletados. Deseja realmente deletar o curso?"))) {
      return false;
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="funcoes_cursos">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cursos[]" value="curso1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cursos[]" value="curso2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cursos[]" value="curso3">

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```